# Replacement fan LED light

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, led

I'm trying to replace an LED light in my fan but I can't figure out what search terms to use to find a replacement bulb.

Based on the documentation my fan came with, the this appears to be a 14 watt bulb.

Does anyone know what these are called and/or where I can find a replacement? I'm in the US if that matters.

[image: LED close up]

[image: LED with cable]

Comment: NOT an off the shelf LED wafer.  Have you found a schematic that may tell you what the part # is or contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: No part # listed anywhere. I have contacted the manufacturer (Fanimation) to see if they can provide guidance. Figured I'd ask here too in case there was an off the shelf solution. Unfortunate that there isn't one.

Comment: What's the model name/number of the fan?

Comment: Fanimation Zonix 54-inch 1-light Ceiling Fan

Answer (score 3):

When they say fixtures are "bulbless", they really mean it. There are no replaceable bulbs in the fixture.

The reason is simple: LED emitters are the most reliable thing in the lamp... probably more reliable than the enclosure.

The typical failure point in a 120V LED light product is the electronic driver module, which is responsible for delivering a constant current to the LED emitter.  Those go bad  because of cheap construction and the finite life of capacitors.

You've managed to pry out the emitters, but they're really not made to be replaceable because the builder never imagined they would fail.  They are not a "bulb" in any sense of the word; there is no non-proprietary source for "ones just like that".

The driver, however, is a different story.  You will find an electronic driver module with 4 wires going to it, and fairly easy to exchange.  It will have a semi-standard form-factor (physical shape).  It will have a *very specific current output* of a relatively standard value, e.g. 350ma, 700ma, 1050ma or 1400ma commonly, and a working voltage range at which it's designed to do that.  If you shop carefully at electronics supply houses, you have a pretty good chance of finding one that ticks all the boxes of form-factor, voltage input, exact current output and output voltage range.

After all, the light manufacturer is not in the business of making drivers; they just grab a commodity OEM driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard "star" metal core printed circuit board, but what's mounted on it is definitely not standard or off the shelf.

The white squares are LED chips, but it's not possible to tell what color of light they should emit by looking at them when they're not powered. They don't have yellow phosphor on it, so they're not blue-pumped phpsphor white LEDs, so if I had to bet, I'd say blue, amber or green. The red rectangles are most likely red LED chips. So if you found this in a nightclub, I'd say blue+red for purple. If you found it in your living room, probably amber+red or green+red for something vaguely white.

They're wired in series of 3 (2 white 1 red) and then the 4 series groups are wired in parallel.

[image]

The parallel wiring means this will turn on unless all 4 groups are blown, which would be surprising, so you should check the power supply first.

It's difficult to tell what voltage or current this uses, so if you want to replace it, first check if there is a label with voltage and current on the power supply. If not, it will probably be simpler to replace both the power supply and the LED. This looks like antique technology, so the power supply is probably past its due date too.

Just google "star PCB led" and you'll find something you can mount in your device, but it probably won't work with the existing power supply.

Comment: Not *that* surprising.  LED emitter arrays like this are typically driven by a constant-*current* driver.  Consider what happens to currents in a series-parallel LED array when one of the series strings burns out.   It's Christmas lights, but inverted!